# Move a range/multiple rows to another sheet based on value in specific column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to move a range (A5:K11 - my spreadsheet only goes A:K) to another tab on my spreadsheet (named Archive) when the cell value in column J is 'Archive'.

This will always be the range that is moved as the rows below will move up into this space.

I can find scripts to move 1 row, but not to move 7 rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
function reMove() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Archive");

  //max 7 to Archive 
  for(var a=0;a<7;a++){

    var values = sourceSheet.getRange("A1:K11").getValues();

      for(var v=0;v<values.length;v++){

        //row J, index 9
        if(values[v][9] == "Archive"){

           destinationSheet.appendRow(values[v]);
           sourceSheet.deleteRow(v+1);
           break;

        }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Move A5:K11 to archive**

```
function move() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dsh=ss.getSheetByName('Archive');
  var srg=ssh.getRange('A5:K11');
  var av=ssh.getRange(5,10,7,1).getValues();//ColumnJ
  var v=srg.getValues();
  var d=0;
  var a=[];
  v.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(av[i][0]=='Archive') {
      dsh.appendRow(r);
      ssh.deleteRow(i+5-d++);
    }
  });                      
}
```

Active Sheet Before:

[image]

Active Sheet After Move:

[image]

Archive Sheet After Move:

[image]